# Issue with React Hooks using Reacstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

I have tried this code various ways with Reactstrap, but as soon as I import the Bootstrap files, all functionality breaks. The code below works just fine if I simply remove the Bootstrap files, but of course I want to use Reactstrap throughout the app, both for the button and the Modal and probably elsewhere throughout the application. Thanks for any help!

Here is my Modal component:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'; 

const LogModalComponent = ({ isShowing, hide }) => isShowing ? ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="modal-wrapper" aria-modal aria-hidden role="dialog">
            <div className="modal">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <Button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close modal" onClick={hide}>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className='modal-body'>
                    <p>Hello I am a modal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>, document.body
  ) : null;

export default LogModalComponent;
```

here is my useModal file:

```
import { useState } from 'react'; 

const useModal = () => {

    const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

    function toggle() {
        setIsShowing(!isShowing);
    }

    return {
        isShowing,
        toggle, 
    }

}

export default useModal;
```

here is my app.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import ReactMapGL, { Marker } from 'react-map-gl'; 
import './index.css';
import { listLogEntries } from './api'; 
import useModal from './useModal'; 
import LogModalComponent from './components/LogModalComponent'; 
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'; 


    const App = () => {
    
        const {isShowing, toggle} = useModal()
    
        const [logEntries, setLogEntries] = useState([]); 
    
        const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
            width: '75vw',
            height: '75vh',
            zoom: 0
        }); 
    
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const logEntries = await listLogEntries(); 
                setLogEntries(logEntries); 
            })(); 
        }, []); 
    
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                        <ReactMapGL
                        {...viewport}
                        mapStyle='mapbox://styles/calcifer2021/ckjx74nhx1gdc17ncj4gappdq'
                        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                        onViewportChange={setViewport}
                        >
                        {
                                logEntries.map(entry => (
                                    <Marker key={entry._id} latitude={entry.latitude} longitude={entry.longitude}>
                                        <svg className='map-marker' alt='map marker' viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="20" height="20" stroke="#F1D11E " strokeWidth="3" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"><path d="M21 10c0 7-9 13-9 13s-9-6-9-13a9 9 0 0 1 18 0z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="10" r="3"></circle></svg>
                                    </Marker>
                                ))
                            }
                        </ReactMapGL>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div>
                        <Button onClick={toggle}>HELLO CLICK ME PLEASE I AM A BUTTON</Button>
                        <LogModalComponent isShowing={isShowing} hide={toggle} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It's super bizarre, when I inspect the element, this is what is showing: <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">HELLO CLICK ME PLEASE I AM A BUTTON</button> There is no Reactstrap button, no onClick, just a plain old button, even though the actual button that is rendering on the screen clearly contains the Reactstrap styling.

Comment: Which bootstrap files are you referring to?

Comment: The bootstrap files I imported in my index.js in order to use reactstrap and bootstrap throughout: import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Comment: Try using bootstrap CDN import in your /public/index.html file 
```<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Unfortunately, this did not correct the issue. I also made sure to import the jquery/popper/etc. in case that was the issue. Still broken.